# UNIBOX jQuery Plugin - Issue with Suggest List (after typing the name)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have issue with Suggestion List in [Unibox Plugin](https://github.com/ddsky/unibox).

The `SearchBar` shows the list of Destinations only when I click on the `Searchbox`, but it doesn't shows `Suggest List` when I type Paris or New York.

I added JSON data file to `SuggestURL`, but this still doesn't work.

```js
// json data for: suggestUrl '/js/data_list.js'

{

  "words": {

    "Destinations": [{ // Iteam List 1
        "id": "1",
        "name": "New York",
        "link": "#",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350"
      },

      { // Item List - 2
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Paris",
        "link": "#",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350"
      }
    ],


    // CATEGORIES
    "Categories": [{ // Item List - 3
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Theme Park",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "link": "#"
      }, { // Item List - 4
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Zoo",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
        "link": "#"
      }

    },





    "suggests": {
      "Destinations": [{ // Iteam List 1
          "id": "1",
          "name": "New York",
          "link": "#",
          "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350"
        },

        { // Item List - 2
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Paris",
          "link": "#",
          "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350"
        }
      ],


      // CATEGORIES
      "Categories": [{ // Item List - 3
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Theme Park",
          "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
          "link": "#"
        }, { // Item List - 4
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Zoo",
          "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
          "link": "#"
        }

      ]
    } // end Suggests
  }
```

```css
#main {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #aaa;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
}
.change_img {
  padding: 30px;
}
#project img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}
#project ui.item.icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
}
ui.item.icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
}
span.imgcity {
  background: url('/img/icon.png') no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
}
#head {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#head form {
  /*style="position:absolute;left: 10px"*/
  /*position:absolute;*/
  /*left: 10px;*/
}
#searchInput {
  width: 350px;
}
#body {
  padding: 20px;
}
#unibox-suggest-box {
  border-width: 10px;
}
/* instant Visual Feedback image size. */

img.unibox-vis {
  width: 70px;
}
/* each search suggest line. */

.unibox-selectable {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
.unibox-selectable .unibox-extra {
  cursor: default;
}
.unibox-selectable:hover .unibox-extra {
  color: #fff;
}
.unibox-selectable.active,
.unibox-selectable:hover {
  background-color: #0078bf;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.unibox-selectable.active a,
.unibox-selectable.active span,
.unibox-selectable.active .unibox-extra,
.unibox-selectable:hover a,
.unibox-selectable:hover span,
.unibox-selectable:hover .unibox-extra {
  color: #fff;
}
.unibox-selectable .unibox-selectable-img-container {
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.unibox-selectable img {
  max-width: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
}
/* Highlight of search keywords in results. */

.unibox-selectable span span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.unibox-ca {
  clear: both;
}
#unibox-invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  height: 0;
  /** needs to get the same styles as the search box so that width of the text within the search box can be computed */
}
/* suggest box */

#unibox-suggest-box {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1500;
}
#unibox-suggest-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#unibox-suggest-box > div > div {
  padding: 6px 8px;
}
#unibox-suggest-box h4 {
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.unibox-ivf {
  position: absolute;
}
.unibox-ivf {
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -89px;
  left: -15px;
}
.unibox-ivf img {
  max-width: 76px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(100%);
}
.unibox-ivf img.l {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0%);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0%);
}
#unibox-dab-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  color: #666;
  border: none #666;
}
#unibox-dab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#unibox-dab:before {
  content: "\00d7";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div id="head">
    <form>
      <input id="searchInput" class="searchbox" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sapien nibh. Donec pharetra, massa ut accumsan hendrerit, justo enim dapibus sapien, vitae bibendum massa nunc nec metus. Pellentesque elementum vulputate ipsum id rutrum. Nam purus
      erat, lobortis at ultrices nec, consequat lacinia dui. Cras augue nunc, ultrices at faucibus non, tristique at ipsum. Nam orci nisl, vestibulum nec accumsan at, malesuada vitae lectus. Cras tincidunt lobortis urna vel finibus.

    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Here comes our unibox configuration -->
<script>
  var boxes = [];


  $(function() {


    var settings = {
      // these are required:
      suggestUrl: '/js/data_list.js', // 'http://yourserver.com/suggests?query=', the URL that provides the data for the suggest
      ivfImagePath: 'http://placehold.it/350x350', //'http://yourserver.com/images/ivf/', the base path for instant visual feedback images
      // these are optional:
      instantVisualFeedback: 'all', // where the instant visual feedback should be shown, 'top', 'bottom', 'all', or 'none', default: 'all'
      throttleTime: 100, // the number of milliseconds before the suggest is triggered after finished input, default: 300ms
      extraHtml: undefined, // extra HTML code that is shown in each search suggest
      highlight: true, // whether matched words should be highlighted, default: true
      queryVisualizationHeadline: '', // A headline for the image visualization, default: empty
      animationSpeed: 200, // speed of the animations, default: 300ms
      enterCallback: function(text, link) {
        console.log('enter callback: ' + text);
      }, // callback on what should happen when enter is pressed, default: undefined, meaning the link will be followed
      enterCallbackResult: function(text, link) {
        console.log('enter callback result: ' + text);
      }, // callback on what should happen when enter is pressed on a result or a suggest is clicked
      placeholder: 'Search for something',
      minChars: 2, // minimum number of characters before the suggests shows, default: 3
      suggestOrder: [], // the order of the suggests
      suggestSelectionOrder: [], // the order of how they should be selected
      noSuggests: '<b>We haven\'t found anything for you, <u>sooorrryyy</u></b>',

      // Sugestion Open List
      emptyQuerySuggests: {
        "suggests": {
          "Destinations": [{
              "id": "1",
              "name": "New York",
              "link": "#",
              "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350"
            },

            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "Paris",
              "link": "#",
              "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350"
            }
          ],


          // CATEGORIES
          "Categories": [{
              "id": "3",
              "name": "Theme Park",
              "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
              "link": "#"
            },

            {
              "id": "4",
              "name": "Zoo",
              "image": "http://placehold.it/350x350",
              "link": "#"
            }
          ]
        } // end Suggests
      }, //end emptyQuerySuggests


      //maxWidth: 400 // the maximum width of the suggest box, default: as wide as the input box
    };

    // apply the settings to an input that should get the unibox
    //       $("#searchInput").unibox(settings);
    //       $(".search").unibox(settings);



    // apply to multiple boxes
    boxes = $(".searchbox").unibox(settings);

  });
</script>
```

I added JSON data for `SuggestUrl` in the "Snippet Code"and the UniBox plugin in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joten/1b3kr1rz/).

Comment: JSFiddle - Update: https://jsfiddle.net/Joten/1b3kr1rz/